# I want to see which typescript code in my library is not used. How to accomplish that?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

how to switch on code lenses for typescript and check which parts have 0 references?

[This is a example picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7mgC.png)
Which settings can display 0 references (like the grey font of picture)?

Answer (score 1):

use below settings

```
  "typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
  "typescript.implementationsCodeLens.enabled": true
```

read more about it here: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10717)